# How can I implement the ability to combine items into new items?

Tags: c#

I would like to understand how to be able to combine items in a player's inventory, producing new items. For example, the scenario I have in mind is that the user picks up three key fragments and combines them to create a complete key.

What properties should I model on my item classes to support this behavior, and what should my basic algorithms be?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Check out the [help] for lots of information about asking questions here, it should be useful to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would expand a bit on Philipp's answer. This is not a very efficient solution, but unless you have millions of items, it should not be too bad.

```
class Item {
  string Name                    // Item name (identifier)
  map(string, string) Properties // Properties of the item, whatever
  string[] Requirements          //Names of items required for creation
}

Item[] allItems                  // Array of all item templates in game

Item CombineItems(Item[] items) 
{
    for item in allItems
    { // Loop through all possible items
        if (item.Requirements.Len() != items.Len()) 
            continue // Skip items with different number of requirements
        bool found = true
        for reqItem in items 
        { // Loop through the items we wish to combine
            if (reqItem.Name not in item.Requirements) 
            { 
                found = false
                break
            }
        }
        if (found == true)        
            return item  // We have found a match, create the item
     }
     return null // Not possible to combine!
}
```

This is a very rigid way of doing things, but should work (wrote this quickly so it probably has some bugs, but you get the idea). **EDIT for clarification**: The code is not C#, but rather pseudo code, but the *idea* should work.

If the function returns something else than null, you know that the merge has succeeded, and you can delete the "ingredients".

**Clarification:**
Assume we have a number of template items. These items do not exist in the game world, but are used to create new items to the game world. The array *allItems* contains these templates. Each item has a name, e.g. "nails", "baseball bat". Each item also has a requirement on what items are needed to create it. So a "nailbat" requires ["nails","baseball bat"].

When we wish to combine items, we call the function **CombineItems** with one argument, an array of items we wish to combine.

The function then searches through the array of template items. For each template item we check that the number required items match the number of items we wish to combine. If it does not match, continue with the next template.

Next, we check that the name of each item we wish to combine is in the requirements for the template item. To create a "nailbat", we search each template for the requirements "nails" and "baseball bat". If we get a match, we can combine the items, and return a new instance of the combined item!

Think of it as a restaurant menu: we have different ingredients, and with a handful of different ingredients we wish to see what dish from the menu we can make (if any at all).

Comment: @user40740 Please use the comments instead of editing the answer.

Comment: I apologize for that. Painless can you please explain line 2 in your pseudo code . i still haven't explored class properties. Also how can i specify which requirements are for this item?. basing off your menu example;if we have a "scrambled eggs" dish from the menu and an array of all the ingredients of all dishes of the menu.how do i make sure than when i create the "scrambled eggs" object it will pick the right requirements from the array?

Comment: Well, the properties of an item don't matter at all for merging items, at least not in my example. It was included just to illustrate the fact that different items have different properties, for example a "nailbat" might have properties ["damage":"10", "range":"1"] and so on.

Comment: @Painless Good answer, the formatting was fine and the explanation was clear, a very good first answer, I hope to see more like them! @user40740 - you have to decide how you want to store these, you can use a parser and file format (such as XML or JSON) to store these property values and load them into the `allItems` list that Painless mentions at the start of the game/scene loading.

Answer (score 1):

A `CombineItems` method needs to do these things in pseudocode:

```
check if the items can be combined. when yes:
    remove the used items
    add the new item
when they can not be combined:
    throw an exception (which can obtionally carry the reason why)
```

The interesting part from the software architecture point of view is where to check which items can be combined with which. You basically have two options here:

1. You have a fixed list of all allowed combinations in your InventorySystem class and check if the provided items have a corresponding entry
2. Each InventoryItem would have its own list of other items it can be combined with. You could then add a method `public InventoryItem CombineWith(InventoryItem other)` to your InventoryItem class. This method would return the resulting item on a positive match or throw the exception when there is no match.

Comment: @Phillip Alright so i need to have a bool value of wither this item can be combined or not and the inventory system would check for this. if it can be combined it will remove the items and create the new combined item. i only want it to combine shattered key pieces so can you illustrate further on that part?

Comment: @user40740 Sorry, but I don't know what exactly you want to read. Please be more specific in your questions.

Comment: alright i am sorry for that.  i want to be able to combine 3 items together to create one item. and only those 3 items are the ones that are able to be combined. if you notice in my code i wanted to pass an array of the items that i want to be combined. but i don't know to actually combine the items to create another one.

Comment: @user40470 Did the user pass an array of exactly 3 items? Is one of them "key fragment 1"? Is one of them "key fragment 2"? Is one of them "key fragment 3"? When all four answers are true, remove the passed items from the inventory and give the player a new "Complete Key" item.

Comment: well i understand that bit. so the scenario should look like this: "user says Combine (x,y,z) it checks if he passed an array of size 3 and if  the  items he wants to  combine can be combined. if so  combine the items by removing 3 key fragments and giving him a complete key. correct?

Comment: how does the user exactly pass an array?

Comment: Please avoid having extended discussions via comments; if you want to have an extended discussion about something, consider moving to [chat].